# How to change the warp-svc 's log directory to /data/log/?

Tags: cloudflare, warp

installed warp-svc on ubuntu
and i noicted the warp-svc will create a log directory in /var/log/cloudflare-warp/
and create some txt files in it
like cfwarp_service_log.txt cfwarp_service_stats.txt ...
i have a disk mounted on /data/ and save all logs in /data/log/

how to change the warp-svc log files dir to /data/log/ ?

thanks

tried to edit /lib/systemd/system/warp-svc.service 's LogsDirectory
but can not change to /data/log/

want to let warp-svc log to /data/log/

Answer (score 0):

I got sick of the volume of data in the cloudflare logs (>2GB) so I added a line to my fstab:

tmpfs   /var/log/cloudflare-warp    tmpfs   rw,nodev,nosuid

This takes care of the proliferation of data, cleared at each shutdown. Whether it can be adapted to provide for your situation exactly depends on whether you can mount a directory as a partition.

mount --bind /data/log/ /var/log/cloudflare-warp may work (but not sure if this can be added to your fstab)